# Add data in excel Data table UIPath

Tags: uipath

I have 3 columns in an excel file and 3 variables(`Age`,`name`,`Family`) that change.
I need to add data each time in a new line.

I create an `Excel Application Scope`, open excel file. Then 3 Assign where filling in variables with values like

```
age = 19
```

Then 3 Add Data Row element and in Data Row field I write variable age. Next Add Data element Name.

But I have error.

Table:

```
Age Name Family
12  Kate  Nooq
```

Comment: Can you add more details of the error you're getting?\

Comment: It's so hard to understand, but should be very easy to do. Improve your text. And show us your process. How far did you come? And what is there error?

Comment: photo of my program https://ibb.co/vZYxKQd

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to write "12, Kate, Nooq" to cells in an Excel file rather than to a datatable in memory. For that you shouldn't be using an Add Data Row activity, instead you could use a [Write Cell](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/excel-write-cell) activity. Writing one cell at a time isn't really the best way of doing this however.

Comment: I already have this line "12, Kate, Nooq". i need add new line below. using my variables

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly I think you want to add the Data Row that you have created to the end of your data, I mean to say Append the Row at the end of your Excel Data.

If that is the case please use **Append Range Activity** and provide you new Data Table with the new Rows added.

You will need to create a temporary data table and add the data rows in that datatable with new rows and use this datatable to the **Append Range Activity**